# Why does a television image rotate to the right when one side of the magnet is applied, and to the left when the other is applied?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

If you have a television that displays the image of a clockwise spiral on a white background, and you apply one side (pole) of a strong magnet such as a good size neodymium iron boron magnet - the image will shift in a rotational fashion to either the left, or the right. If you switch the pole, the image will rotate in a direction that is opposite to the initial rotation.

I uploaded pictures of this here: 
[image: magnet tv]

I was wondering if anyone can explain why this happens?

Comment: The colored dipole field lines are the awesomest part of these pictures!

Comment: I suggest that you are very careful as a magnet near a cathode ray tube might produce a colour convergence problem. This is when the three colour pictures produced on the screen are misaligned relative to one another and the picture has coloured edges. A magnet might permanently magnetise parts of the tube responsible for deflecting the electron beams and cause the deflection of the three electron beams responsible for producing the colours to be permanently misaligned.

Answer (score 4):

Your television is a [cathode ray tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube), containing an electron beam which is steered by internal magnetic fields towards the different pixels that make up the screen.  Adding a constant magnetic field introduces additional steering due to the Lorentz magnetic force, $\vec F = q\vec v \times \vec B$.

The image *rotates* because the force is perpendicular to the velocity and to the field direction.  When the field and the dipole axis are parallel or antiparallel, the perpendicular parts of the field are due to the way it spreads out as it leaves the dipole.  These are different at the north end and the south end, as you can see below --- the electrons on either side of the magnet are deflected in opposite directions, which would reverse if you reversed the field by turning the magnet around.

[image: pole towards screen]

If you rotate the magnet so that the dipole axis is parallel to the screen, all the steering comes from the return field, and the direction is much less complicated:

[image: pole parallel to screen]

You can actually get a better sense of what's happening if you make the television display a pure blue screen (which was the default for some VCRs and DVD players for a while when there wasn't any input).  The blue pixels are sandwiched between the red and the green, so you'll be able to tell which part of the beam is steered which way by the color change.

A fun project is to use a compass needle to determine the direction of the field from your magnet, then use that information and the Lorentz force to convince yourself that the cathode rays inside the television are negatively charged.  Or vice-versa: from the electron deflection, figure out which end of your magnet is "north".

Comment: Yes that is how the television is affected, but could you clarify exactly why one side of the magnet warps the image counter clockwise and the other clockwise? I didn't catch that in your answer?

Comment: One end is the north pole, and the other end is the south pole. So turning the magnet around reverses the field direction $\vec B$, which reverses the direction of the force $\vec F$.

Comment: Here is an illustration of the magnetic field: http://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/~infocom/Ideas/graphics/magnet.gif I can't see any type of rotation included there, it's direct attract/repel - my question then is, where does the actual rotation of the image come from? Why would a simple attract and repel field rotate the image? Apologize if I am not being clear enough here